# PHP datetime to W3CDTF like 1994-11-05T08:15:30-05:00 syntax for RSS or Atom feeds

Tags: php, datetime, rss, feed, atom-feed

I have date time like `2017-07-23 10:05:50` but i need `2017-07-23T10:05:50-05:00`

I have try with --

> date('Y-m-dTH:i:s', strtotime($old_date)); // Return :
>   2017-07-23CEST10:26:41

But this is not valid https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/error/InvalidW3CDTFDate.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
date('c', strtotime($old_date));
```

Comment: Exactly. It Will Output `2017-07-23T10:37:42+02:00`

Comment: Great Help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Class DateTime has some predefined datetime formats.

Maybe this could help...
http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php